# What is the best way to automate pulling data from a Tableau report download into an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba, tableau-api

I have an existing Excel spreadsheet that performs several calculations to assign an ordering status to 200+ items ie. "Need to order" or "Good." There is an On-Hand Quantity column that needs to be updated daily with values from a Tableau report. The 200+ items all have unique item codes that exist in both the Tableau report and the Excel sheet. The sheet currently uses VLOOKUP functions to pull numbers from the Tableau download into the Excel sheet. What is the easiest way to automate this function using Macros? I am familiar with macros but have not created anything like this that would allow users to upload the Tableau download into a worksheet drop-in and automatically populate the appropriate values in a sheet of the workbook.

Hope this makes sense, I appreciate all the support and help in advance!

Comment: I personally wouldn't use VLOOKUP or VBA for this but the built in Power Query functions

Comment: Excel can connect to databases, I would explore connecting the spreadsheet to the source of the tableau report and skip tableau all together.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.